# How to continue line when data is null or zero?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Note: I'm using d3 v5

I'm creating a graph to represent some of my teams historical data. Some time periods of data are missing, how do I interpolate or even just continue the line between the two non-null data values?

I've tried using defined, but that results in gaps in the data, and I've also tried simply passing the data into d3 as null but it treats the same as if I passed in a zero instead.
Here is an example of my graph with the data being passed in as nulls and not using defined.

[image: example]

And here is an example of my graph with the data as null still and using defined.

[image: example]

Here is the code that I use for generating my lines

```
types.forEach(function (val) {
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return xScale(d.date);
        }) // set the x values for the line generator
        .y(function (d) {
            return yScale(d[val]);
        });
    // 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
        .attr("stroke", colors[val])
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
        .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
});
```

My end goal here is if there is a gap in data, a line is just drawn straight between the two closest non-null values.

2/11/19 Edit:

I tried what was mentioned below, I didn't auto include all values in my dataset, only including those that had values.

Here is an excerpt of my data.

```
var data = [{
    date: "9/28/2017",
    value1: 117.043121149897,
    value2: 133.88090349076,
    value3: 131.279945242984
}, {
    date: "9/29/2017",
    value1: 117.316906228611,
    value2: 133.88090349076,
    value3: 131.279945242984
}, {
    date: "11/7/2017",
    value1: 117.864476386037,
    value2: 134.907597535934,
    value3: 130.800821355236,
    value4: 166.666666666667,
    value5: 168.195300022815
}, {
    date: "11/8/2017",
    value1: 117.864476386037,
    value2: 134.907597535934,
    value3: 130.800821355236,
    value4: 195.893223819302,
    value5: 168.195300022815
}, {
    date: "11/9/2017",
    value1: 117.864476386037,
    value2: 134.907597535934,
    value3: 130.869267624914,
    value4: 195.893223819302,
    value5: 168.195300022815
}];
```

As you can see, I only include values when they are valid numbers, but since I have done this I am having issues with the chart generating. It doesn't seem to like values being missing, as the line stops generating as soon as it hits a missing value, which for some lines is immediately, and others later on.

Here is the current graph:

[image: example]

Here is a block with my current code: https://blockbuilder.org/ctooley21/c4c455c20eea8d7018e92bd3c348d35e the javascript array is dynamically generated with c# asp.net

Comment: Could just fill the array with missing dates and mean values before passing to d3

Comment: there's never any missing dates, just dates that don't have some of the values set. I figured I could probably do it before passing to d3 but I was hoping d3 would have a way to do it natively

Comment: Same principle.... filling missing value properties with mean values based on previous and next valid ones

Comment: just remove these points from the dataset, you get a connecting line between points

Comment: @ctooley17 You don't need to calculate averages or something like that, actually you don't need to do anything! Just pass the data array you have to the line generator and the path will jump from a point to the other, continuously. We use the `define()` method in the exact opposite scenario, that is, when **we don't want** the line jumping from a data point to the next. So, just pass the data as it is, without values for some dates. On the other hand, if you are receiving that data array already with the null values, just filter them out.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado and rioV8, I have tried what you both mentioned, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I have edited my post.

Comment: @ctooley17 It's nice that you have edited the question, but this is hard to debug without the rest of the code, specially the scales. So, it's a good idea creating a running version of the problem, using [blockbuilder](https://blockbuilder.org) or something like that.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have edited with a block. Thanks for being patient, I am still a bit new to posting on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here can be explained by the structure of your data: you have everything in a huge array of objects, but not every object has the `workstation`, `laptop`, `tablet`, `macOS`, `ios` and `display` properties. Because of that, you have `undefined` when using the line generator the way you're using (more on that below), which will give `NaN`s and a huge amount of errors (check your console).

The simplest solution without refactoring your code too much is filtering the data for each property inside the loop:

```
var thisData = data.filter(function(d){
    return d[val];
});
```

Here is the updated blockbuilder: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/bdd84ce289f7868183681e4d631e1488

[image]

PS: as a rule of thumb, **do not** use loops to append elements in a D3 code.

Comment: Thank you! So for best practices I should separate each of the lines of data into their own arrays?

Comment: oh, I don't need any help. I was just making sure that was the d3 standard